# Git accidental overwrite

Tags: git, github

I pushed some changes to my repo from let's say computer A and then accidentaly pushed and older state from computer B. How can I revert back to the version from the A computer (I don't know the code of the version I want to revert to)?

Please help or mark me the original question beacuse I couldn't find any help.

Comment: Please be more specific - Do you still have the state on computer A? Can you still access computer A? Was it a force-push? Did you fetch/pull into computer B before you pushed from it? By "revert" do you literally mean "git revert" or not necessarily?

Answer (score 0):

Check the commits/diff with cmd **git log** and then push based on commit

```
git reset --hard <old-commit-id>
git push -f <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

Comment: I can't find the version I need

Comment: did you know the commits message or anything regarding that push from A system?

Comment: I kinda know the commit message

Comment: Find the commit id follow above steps.

Comment: git log --name-status

Comment: I'm just going to do the commit again from the other computer when I get there.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the previous commit from the log and then push based on the history

```
git log
git reset --hard <id>
git push -f <remote-name> <branch-name>
```